# Getting type mismatch error when run this code in swift

Tags: swift, casting, ios8

I am creating outlet Collection of ImageView and a custom class "TTTImageView" for their properties . I want to add TapGestureRecognizer on all ImageView but I found this error

"NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

My ViewController.swift class is look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet var fields: [TTTImageView]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpLogic()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func setUpLogic(){
    for index in 0 ... fields.count-1{
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "fieldTapped")
        gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}

func fieldTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    var img = recognizer.view as TTTImageView
    img.setPlayer("x")


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

and TTTImageView.swift is :

```
import UIKit

 class TTTImageView: UIImageView {
var player : String = String()

func setPlayer(player : String){
    self.player = player
    if(player == "x"){
        self.image = UIImage(named: "alphabet X")
    }
    else{
        self.image = UIImage(named: "alphabet O")
    }
}

}
```

I think it's a type-cast problem but don't know how to solve. Please get me out from this problem. Thanks

Comment: what line is that error happening on?

Comment: on this line.   fields[index].addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

Comment: Did you do a clean build? Doesn't seem wrong on first sight.

Comment: Also do you get a compiler or runtime-error?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is this

```
@IBOutlet var fields: [TTTImageView!]
```

instead of this

```
@IBOutlet var fields: [TTTImageView]!
```

?

Note the placement of the ! character.